# How to extract objects from array on the base of area_id

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, filter

I've an array of customers and I want to extract customers into a new array on the base of area_id.here is my array,like if I give area_id 7,it should returns a new array of all the customers having area_id 7

```
"customers": [
            {
                "id": "5",
                "aname": "Sts Customers",
                "type": "2",
                "address": "house no e 4",
                "area_id": "7",
                "cell_no": "03334488",
                "opn_type": "Debit",
                "opngbl": "2564",
                "lat": "33.7997",
                "longi": "73.04052769999998",
                "company_id": "1",
                "acct_no": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "14",
                "aname": "New Customer",
                "type": "2",
                "address": "house no 4",
                "area_id": "8",
                "cell_no": "7878",
                "opn_type": "Credit",
                "opngbl": "2541",
                "lat": "33.7997",
                "longi": "73.04052769999998",
                "company_id": "1",
                "acct_no": ""
            },
            {
                "id": "15",
                "aname": "one more customer",
                "type": "2",
                "address": "jjkhklj",
                "area_id": "8",
                "cell_no": "8876987",
                "opn_type": "Credit",
                "opngbl": "454",
                "lat": "33.7997",
                "longi": "73.04052769999998",
                "company_id": "1",
                "acct_no": ""
            }
        ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
customers.filter((customer) => {
  return customer.area_id == 7
})
```